# Encountered two children with the same key (react-native, js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have encountered this problem `` Encountered two children with the same key, `11`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version ``.

The problem is I have checked my `fetch`, where I'm getting array for FlatList and I have no items with `id=11` and there is no such `id` at all.

Here is my `FlatList` component:

```
<FlatList
         horizontal
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         style={styles.myPatientsList}
         data={clients}
         renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <MyPatientsCard {...item} goToScreen={this.goToScreen} />
          )}
         keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
         ListEmptyComponent={
            <Text style={styles.noClientsText}>
              {I18n.t('expertScreen.noPatients')}
            </Text>
           }
/>
```

Comment: What is `clients`? An array? If the elements get rendered as `<MyPatientsCard>`, then it looks like `{...item}` is defining the key? (my point is we don't have enough information to give meaningful answers)

Comment: Is the `renderItem` function called on a loop to create multiple cards?